# Code signing of embedded firmware: Is a CRC enough when the firmware is encrypted?

Tags: encryption, embedded, code-signing, firmware

I'm writing a firmware for an embedded system (microcontroller). The firmware can be updated by a bootloader (also written by me).

Now there is a requirement to take measures to prevent manipulation of the firmware, so the system must only execute a downloaded firmware if it has some sort of a valid signature.

The firmware file comes encrypted. It is decrypted by the bootloader (in the microcontroller) and then programmed into the flash memory.

Since the firmware comes encrypted, in my opinion a simple CRC check on the flash content should be sufficient to prove the firmware validity. But I'm no expert for cyber security, so... do I need more?

I presume that the encryption is strong enough and that the flash memory cannot be read out.

Comment: CRC and encryption aren't really related. The CRC is there to ensure flash integrity, the encryption is there to protect the data from intruders. However, if the checksum itself isn't encrypted, it is possible to reverse engineer which CRC algorithm that was used. Meaning that it would be possible to change flash without getting any CRC errors. But since the flash memory is read protected anyway, I don't see how any of this matters.

Comment: A CRC is useless for detecting intentional modification, it's trivial to defeat. You must have a MAC or digital signature of some kind to detect tampering. You don't mention how keys are managed, but proper use of AES-GCM will provide encryption and tamper-detection in one pass.

Comment: No, a CRC is not enough.  But there are encryption algorithms that can provide what you need.  Choose an encryption algorithm that provides _integrity_ and/or _authentication_ in addition to _confidentiality_.  Integrity ensures the information has not been tampered with.  Authentication ensures the information is from an official source.

Comment: What @Lundin said. If you have checked the encryption, you have validated the transfer process into your system. After that it is only a matter of unintentional data loss in the flash which you (if your assumptions are right) have to protect against. This of course is a very weak form of security but justifiable in many circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for all there answers. To make things a bit clearer: The CRC is part of the encrypted firmware, so not manipulatable unless the encryption is broken. The microcontroller has no hardware encryption support (like AES) and only very limited ressources at all.

Comment: If the CRC is encrypted along with the firmware it's unclear what kind of security you expect from that. If an attacker can successfully modify the encrypted firmware they can also modify the CRC, obviously. In general, [encrypt and *then* authenticate](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac)..

Answer (score 3):

> Since the firmware comes encrypted, in my opinion a simple CRC check
>   on the flash content should be sufficient to prove the firmware
>   validity. But I'm no expert for cyber security, so... do I need more?

If you chose a sound cryptography method, and guard your encryption keys properly, and you also guarantee that the firmware cannot be read-out after it has been transferred, and the bootloader rejects the firmware if it cannot successfully decrypt it, then you already guarantee firmware validity. Unless one of the above assumptions is violated, only the person who owns the keys to encrypt the firmware can ever produce a firmware that will be accepted by the bootloader.

As others have pointed out, CRC is not used to protect against intentional modification as you could just append trash-data to any file to produce the desired CRC. However I'd still recommend to have a CRC on at least two stages of your firmware-upgrade process:

- CRC the encrypted data during transmission, preferably on each transmitted packet so you can re-transmit single packets without restarting the whole process (i.e. CRC over 256-byte chunks of the encrypted data)
- Second over the flash area occupied by the firmware (minus bootloader) against a CRC of the decrypted firmware that is generated by the bootloader after successful decryption (or a static, fixed CRC, some µC-IDEs support this built-in), to make sure no flash-write-errors occured. It's common practice to safe this CRC-value to some flash area that is not part of the CRC, so that the bootloader can verify the application's integrity on every device reset.